# PayPal Payouts "Sender has insufficient funds" in Sandbox

Tags: ruby, paypal

I'm trying to setup a `PayPal Payout`. I've got my API calls going through but in the sandbox I keep getting: `Sender has insufficient funds`. How can I add funds to my application? I can't seem to find an option to specify an account to send from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the mass payments you must have the PayPal balance . For the sandbox while creating the account it prompt you to specify the amount to show in the PayPal balance . But if you have missed that , you can create the new sandbox account and specifying the amount this time .

Otherwise you can provide your sandbox email address I can transfer you the money from my sandbox account to continue with the same sandbox account .

Comment: thanks for suggestion. I created an account and transferred money from there.It worked!

Answer (score 4):

The answer possibly could be, that you have several currencies, say, EUR and you have a EUR balance of 1000, but you are trying to payout in USD. 
So, what you should do, is login to sandbox.paypal.com using the test account, and level the currencies, so, transfer EUROs to USDs and now retry the payment, and it should succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Just and update on this question

Now you can directly add balance to the sandbox account by editing the PayPal balance from your "Developer dashboard"

Hope it helps!

[image]
[image]